# Installing WSO2 greg and API manager on different VM with shared MySQL

Tags: mysql, wso2, wso2-api-manager

I'm installing greg and APi manager using this configuration:

1 VM for MySQL

1 VM for API

1 VM for BAM

1 VM for greg

All latest currrent releases

I'm wandering which is the best configuration.

My idea was having all the tool to place data in MySQL, but I'm wandering on how to ling all the DB in the various config files
APi should point to registry runniong on his VM and to the BAM instance, but looking on the registru moaster-datasource.xml I found also this:

```
<datasource>
        <name>WSO2AM_DB</name>
        <description>The datasource used for API Manager database</description>
        <jndiConfig>
            <name>jdbc/WSO2AM_DB</name>
        </jndiConfig>
        <definition type="RDBMS">
            <configuration>
                <url>jdbc:h2:repository/database/WSO2AM_DB;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE</url>
                <username>wso2carbon</username>
                <password>wso2carbon</password>
                <driverClassName>org.h2.Driver</driverClassName>
                <maxActive>50</maxActive>
                <maxWait>60000</maxWait>
                <testOnBorrow>true</testOnBorrow>
                <validationQuery>SELECT 1</validationQuery>
                <validationInterval>30000</validationInterval>
            </configuration>
        </definition>
    </datasource>
```

That imply that registry has access to API manager DB ... what for?

I'll have to add also ESB and BPS so this deployment architecture becomes complex.
Any hints
Thanks
Luca

Answer (score 0):

WSO2 servers are using H2 database which is shipped by default. So if you start up a fresh pack which will run on its own database instance.

In order to share the registry data between servers, you will have to configure registry mounting. [This](http://ajithvblogs.blogspot.com/2012/09/create-jdbc-mount-to-wso2-governance.html) will be helpful to create JDBC mounting. But if you have one instance of a server, then you can omit clustering part from the article. You can follow the same configuration for other servers as well (BAM, API manager and BPS) to configure JDBC mounting. So that all your data will be stored in MySql and shared across servers.

If you need to store users information also in JDBC and share it across servers, then you will have to add another data source into master-datasource.xml and use it in CARBON-HOME/repository/conf/user-mgt.xml instead of the default data source.

API manager is having few different data sources for its own purposes. That doesn't mean to have any relationship with registry. By default "WSO2CarbonDB" is only used for registry and user manager purposes as stated in the description of each data sources.

Comment: 'll try to explain better:  
I want to have 1 MYSQL server  
One Registry that uses MySQL instead of H2  
The API manager will be on a different host and use the same MySQL and the registry to store stuff, so it will need to put something in MySQL and something will just be pointing to existing registry  
Than there will be the BAM also on another host  
What can be placed in the MySQl what can be just a pointer to the registry?
This part is not clear  
4) Open the axis2.xml and enable clustering. (GREG_HOME/repository/conf/axis2)  
Is this mandatory since there are more product that point it?

Comment: You need clustering only when you have more than one instances of a particular product. Let's say if you have two of more API managers, then in order to communicate between API manager instances, you will need clustering. You can use BAM to store your statistics and you can configure BAM to use Mysql as well. Basically, you will have to mount registry of relevant products in Mysql. So that everyone will share the registry.

Comment: So to see if I understood well: I can have 1 MySQL where I create first a GREG DB and than create a BAM and a API Manager that point to the same MySQL GREG DB instead of having their own instance (this for the REG instance, but keep conf and local on the VM of each product)

Answer (score 0):

You can use mounted database to resolve your issue . please refer [1] for how to mount guide.

[1]. http://ajithvblogs.blogspot.com/2012/09/create-jdbc-mount-to-wso2-governance.html

Thank You,
Dharshana

Comment: in the referred "how to" there is a step where I'm required to "Open the axis2.xml and enable clustering" both on GREG AND ESB is this always needed or only if the product that I want to mount to GREG is clustered? It seems that GREG need it to alert all mounting products of changes and single mounting instances need it to be aligned on changes, so in the case I'm sharing a single GREG between 1 ESB and 1 APIman do I have to activate clustering? Thanks Luca

Comment: Clustering and mounting are 2 different scenarios. But for enable cashing between mounted nodes you need to set <clustering class="org.apache.axis2.clustering.tribes.TribesClusteringAgent" enable="true"/>

Comment: You can refer http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/Governance453/Remote+Instance+and+Mount+Configuration+Details for further clarifications